# Export git repository to svn

Tags: svn, git

cloning an svn repository into git is easy with git-svn. However, I need to do it the other way round.
I have a git repository lying around and want to import it into an empty (except from trunk, branches and tags folders) keeping all the commit information.

I cerate a git-svn-clone of the svn repo, pulled the git master and dcommitted. However the only commit I have in svn then is the one saying "merged from git"

I also tried the other way: Cloned the git repositoy and called git svn init but git keeps saying "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history."

Is it somehow possible to create an svn repository from git?

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when pulling the master branch from the other repo git creates a merge commit, because there is no common history.

you should use `git pull --rebase` (which will change commit ids, as it recreates the commits) instead, then dcommit

---

you could also try the following:

checkin the initial version with svn (simply creating those branches, tags, trunk folders and committing) first, then create a git svn clone (`git svn -s clone svn://…`)

then issue the following commands:

```
# create a ref to your "svn" commit
git checkout -b svn
# get all your "git" commits
git fetch $your_remote_git_repo
# create a ref to your "git" commit
git branch master FETCH_HEAD
# rebase the rest your git commits
git rebase svn master
# commit to svn!
git svn dcommit
```

**edit** cherry pick was only necessary because my quickly set up git repository had only empty commits

Comment: I tried it with git pull --rebase but it destroys the svn upstream information:
# git svn clone -s <svn-url>
# cd project
# git pull --rebase  git:project
# git svn dcommit
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 517.

Comment: try to create a dummy commit with svn first

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood what you mean: After git svn clone I created a test commit in svn. After git pull --rebase I can still git svn fetch, but not dcommit. I think about just importing into svn ignoring the history.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I just made it by pulling the git repository in another branch and cherry-picking all 53 commits into the svn branch (master). Afterwards I was able to git svn dcommit

Comment: So what is the correct/preferred solution? There appear to be three options here.

Answer (score 12):

Here is my recipe for publishing a git repo via svn:

```
svn mkdir --parents http://host/path/to/repo/{trunk,tags,branches} \
    -m "Standard layout for $project"
git svn init -s http://host/path/to/repo/
git svn fetch
git rebase trunk master
git svn dcommit
```

Subversion won't preserve commit times or authorship.
God help you if you used branches.

Comment: After doing the `rebase`, git reports that the two repos have now diverged badly.  What should one do to rectify that?